# DCOS Slaves : add placement constraints

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I Have installed a DCOS cluster with the guidance of below link(https://dcos.io/docs/1.10/installing/custom/advanced/).

Now, DCOS cluster up and running.I want to add "Placement Constraints" for the applications that host top of DCOS cluster.

I added parameters(MESOS_ATTRIBUTES=SPACE:RACK1) into 
/opt/mesosphere/etc/mesos-slave-common file. After I added the, I could not up the dcos-mesos-slave service again

Could you please advise me how to approach this by using above DCOS installation method.

etc # cat mesos-slave-common

```
MESOS_MASTER=zk://zk-1.zk:2181,zk-2.zk:2181,zk-3.zk:2181,zk-4.zk:2181,zk-5.zk:2181/mesos
MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos
MESOS_EXTERNAL_LOG_FILE=/var/log/mesos/mesos-agent.log
MESOS_MODULES_DIR=/opt/mesosphere/etc/mesos-slave-modules
MESOS_CONTAINER_LOGGER=com_mesosphere_mesos_JournaldLogger
MESOS_ISOLATION=cgroups/cpu,cgroups/mem,disk/du,network/cni,filesystem/linux,docker/runtime,docker/volume,volume/sandbox_path,volume/secret,posix/rlimits,namespaces/pid,linux/capabilities,com_mesosphere_MetricsIsolatorModule,cgroups/devices,gpu/nvidia
MESOS_DOCKER_VOLUME_CHECKPOINT_DIR=/var/lib/mesos/isolators/docker/volume
MESOS_IMAGE_PROVIDERS=docker
MESOS_NETWORK_CNI_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/mesosphere/etc/dcos/network/cni
MESOS_NETWORK_CNI_PLUGINS_DIR=/opt/mesosphere/active/cni/:/opt/mesosphere/active/dcos-cni/:/opt/mesosphere/active/mesos/libexec/mesos
MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/mesos/slave
MESOS_SLAVE_SUBSYSTEMS=cpu,memory
MESOS_LAUNCHER_DIR=/opt/mesosphere/active/mesos/libexec/mesos
MESOS_EXECUTOR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES=file:///opt/mesosphere/etc/mesos-executor-environment.json
MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT=10mins
MESOS_CGROUPS_ENABLE_CFS=true
MESOS_CGROUPS_LIMIT_SWAP=false
MESOS_DISALLOW_SHARING_AGENT_PID_NAMESPACE=true
MESOS_DOCKER_REMOVE_DELAY=1hrs
MESOS_DOCKER_STOP_TIMEOUT=20secs
MESOS_DOCKER_STORE_DIR=/var/lib/mesos/slave/store/docker
MESOS_GC_DELAY=2days
MESOS_HOSTNAME_LOOKUP=false
GLOG_drop_log_memory=false
MESOS_ATTRIBUTES=SPACE:RACK1
```

Answer (score 0):

Mesos attributes should be added to `/var/lib/dcos/mesos-slave-common`, not `/opt/mesosphere/etc/mesos-slave-common`. Note that you may need to create this file the first time.

### Steps

1. Stop the slave: `systemctl stop dcos-mesos-slave`
2. Add your attributes to `/var/lib/dcos/mesos-slave-common`
3. Clean out old live executors: `rm -f /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/latest`
4. Start the slave: `systemctl restart dcos-mesos-slave`